# Python embedded in RubyOnRails

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make a site like Codeacademy. Where users can learn Python online,
solve problems and master theory.

Framework for the server is Ruby On Rails

I am trying to understand how can I translate python's code to the server, then execute this code on the server? Any python's interpreters created in Ruby? I totally can not understand how this should work.

Python's version: 2.7 or 3.5 (Not fundamentally)

Thank you for attention

Comment: it's a really bad idea to use a real terminal and let the user execute code on your server, you need to use a python interpreter written in javascript like http://pypyjs.org/ so it's just javascript

Comment: At the moment, there are no Python implementations written in Ruby, although there *was* a project for a Python implementation on top of the Rubinius Language Framework (typhon, it never had more than a README and an empty directory, though). There *is* funnily enough a Ruby implementation on top of the PyPy Language Framework, but that is not feature-complete (and seems abandoned). Note that having users execute arbitrary code is a *really bad idea* unless you know *exactly* what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other have stated, there are serious security implications for letting users blindly run things on your server, but if you really wanted to, you could write the python to a file and then execute the python using `system "python #{file_path}"`.

I'm not too familiar with python, but you could probably switch stdout and stderr to write to files and then read those files to get any print statements.

Comment: or `\`python #{file_path}\``. back ticks work the same